# WooCommerce Cart not updating after one product added

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WordPress site in which when I add first product it adds but after that cart does not update. 
I have tried almost everything like deactivating cache, checking database for not having ID in auto increment mode, deactivating/activating plugins, headers expiry and all. If there is any other way than these, please help me out.

Comment: Give more information. What is the theme ? are you use Ajax method ?

Comment: theme is beyoga. no i am not usind ajax methods..